# Is it reasonable to think of the expectation of an infinite-dimensional vector?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, a random vector is an $\mathcal{F}$-measurable mapping $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k}: X(\omega) = (X_{1}(\omega), X_{2}(\omega),\ldots,X_{k}(\omega))$ for finite $k$ and the expectation of $X$ can be defined as $E(X) = (E(X_{1}), E(X_{2}),\ldots,E(X_{k}))$.

Now suppose $X: \Omega \rightarrow l_{p}$ is $\mathcal{F}$--measurable. Does it make sense to define the expectation of $X$ as $E(X) = (E(X_{1}), E(X_{2}),\ldots) \in l_{p}$? Are there any infinite-dimensional oddities that are going to occur when thinking about expectation of a random element of a $l_{p}$ in this way? What about if one wants to think about *conditional* expectation?

Also, if the above definition does actually make sense, can you provide a reference or a field/subfield where you have seen it used so I can read more about it?

Comment: Component expectation seems quite reasonable to me.

Comment: Google "Bochner integral."  Everything works fine except for a technical separability condition, which in the case of $\ell^p$ is automatically satisfied.

Comment: Oh, and conditional expectation works as well.

Comment: Extremely helpful--thanks. Would have marked that as the answer to the question.