# When is the Bochner expectation equal to the vector whose coefficients are the expectations of the random coefficients?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

This question is sort of a follow-up to [one that was posted a couple years ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627436/is-it-reasonable-to-think-of-the-expectation-of-an-infinite-dimensional-vector).

Let $B$ be a Banach space with a countable basis $b := (b_1, b_2, \ldots)$. Let $X$ be a Bochner-integrable $B$-valued random vector, and let $(X_1, X_2, \ldots)$ be its [random] coefficients with respect to $b$.

I'm wondering if there are any simple sufficient conditions for the Bochner expectation of $X$ to be equal to the vector whose coefficients with respect to $b$ are the expectations of the random coefficients $(\mathbb{E} X_1, \mathbb{E} X_2, \ldots)$.

That is, are there are any simple sufficient conditions on $B$ and/or $X$ such that
$$\mathbb{E} X = \sum_i (\mathbb{E} X_i) b_i$$

Of course, this works when $B$ is finite-dimensional. I would like to know if it holds more generally, but I've browsed some summaries of Bochner and Pettis integrals and haven't seen it addressed.

I would also be interested to know the answer for the same question, but with Pettis expectations instead of Bochner expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This always holds.

If $b_1,\dots$ is a basis for $B$ then it's a standard theorem that the coefficient functionals are bounded: There exist $\pi_j\in B^*$ with $$x=\sum_j\pi_j(x)b_j\quad(x\in B).$$And it's a theorem that the Bochner integral commutes with bounded linear operators, so $$\pi_j\Bbb E[X]=\Bbb E[\pi_j(X)]=\Bbb E[X_j],$$which says exactly that $$\Bbb E[X]=\sum_j\Bbb E[X_j]b_j.$$Similarly for the Pettis integral, except then the fact that the integral commutes with bounded linear functionals is part of the definition instead of being an easy theorem.

**Edit** This raises the question of why $\pi_j$ is bounded. One of those things that seemed impossibly deep years ago... I cheated and looked at [Wikipedia on Schuder Bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis). The proof there is wrong, but it led me to a correct proof.

Define $$S_nx=\sum_{j=1}^n\pi_j(x)b_j.$$

(The proof on Wikipedia deduces boundedness of $||S_n||$, and hence of $||\pi_j||$, from Banach-Steinhaus. This is wrong; we can't apply Banach-Steinhaus *until* we know that $S_n$ is bounded (at which point we already know that $\pi_j$ is bounded)!)

Let $c_0(B)$ be the Banach space of sequences of elements of $B$ that tend to $0$ in norm (with norm $||(y_1,y_2\dots)||=\sup_j||y_j||_B$). Define $T:B\to c_0(B)$ by $$Tx=(x-S_1x,x-S_2x,\dots).$$It follows from the Closed Graph Theorem that $T$ is bounded. Hence each $S_n$ is bounded, hence $\pi_j$ is bounded (and in fact $||S_n||$ is bounded, so $||\pi_j||$ is bounded.)

To show $T$ is bounded, suppose $x_n\to x$ in $B$ and $Tx_n\to(y_1,y_2,\dots)$ in $c_0(B)$. We need to show that $Tx=(y_1,y_2,\dots)$.

Now, $x_n-\pi_1(x_n)b_1\to y_1$ in $B$; since $x_n\to x$ this shows that there exists $c_1$ so that $\pi_1x_n\to c_1$ and $y_1=x-c_1b_1$. Similarly $\pi_2x_n\to c_2$ and $y_2=x-(c_1b_1+c_2b_2)$. Etc. Since $||y_j||\to0$ this shows that $$x=\sum_{j=1}^\infty c_jb_j.$$So $c_j=\pi_jx$; hence $y_j=x-S_jx$ and so $Tx=(y_1,y_2,\dots)$, as required.

Comment: Yeah, that looks right to me. Thanks! I guess I just assumed that if this fact was true in general, then it would be pointed out explicitly in at least one of the Bochner integration tutorials that I glanced over.

Comment: Actually, would you mind pointing me to a proof that the $\pi_j$ is a bounded functional? Or giving me a hint at how to prove it?

Comment: I tried searching, but "coefficient functional" doesn't seem to be a standard term. I can see why it's bounded if we had a finite basis, using Kreyszig Lemma 2.4-1 which says that for any finite basis, there exists a constant $c$ such that the sum of the absolute coefficients is $\leq$ $c$ times the norm. Is a fact like that true for countably infinite linear combinations too?

Comment: @student45 Added a proof to the answer.